# keeping program running using "for" loop

Tags: python-2.7

I have been given a homework but don't know how to write some part of it explained as following:

..."In addition make sure your program keeps running until the user enters “quit”. To keep your program running you should use “for” statements. However, for statements doesn’t provide your program to run to infinity. Therefore, for your range value, give the maximum value that your OS can handle. For example; if you are using a 32 bit OS and interpreter, your computer should use 2^31 as the maximum value. "

What did our teacher mean do you think?(PYTHON 2.7)

Comment: He meant what is written above... although it's strange not to use while instead. Anyway, please explain what you understand and what you don't. If it's all gibberish than re-read your book/notes/... first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make mention about the language.

**Java program:**

```
do {
    //Show information
    //Execute preliminar code
    //Here you can get the Exit command
} while (Exit command is true);
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: I didn't feel a need to write python as it is python-2.7 tagged but okay I will mention the language after this time.
Thank you for answer but don't know any java.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could write a code that consistently asks the user for an input. For example:

```
    number = int(input("Enter integer less than 5: "))
    while number>5:
         print("Try again")
         number = int(input("enter integer number"))
         if number == quit:
              break
```

If I did this correctly, this program will continue until one of two conditions is met, 1) you enter a number less than five OR 2) you enter the word quit

Comment: your code doesn't work and we are not suppossed to use "while" because we are not thaught of it yet.Thank you for the tip after all.I learned something new.

Comment: Sorry about that, okay no problem. All you have learned so far is for loops? Have you learned anything about if  and else statements?

Comment: funtion definitions,if-else,and other basic things.

Answer (score 0):

As I learned later,we were supposed to use

```
 for i in range(2**31):

      #Your program codes apart from function definitions are here.
                             .
    string=raw_input("Enter quit to exit.")
    if (string == "quit"):
        break
```